# TypeScript error with object being undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm getting in TypeScript and as part of a Angular component I'm trying to set properties on an object I have defined, but I keep getting an

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'ooyalaId' of undefined
```

This is how I'm setting the property:

```
    @Input() data: Media;
  options: Video;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.data.ooyalaVideo);
    this.options.ooyalaId = this.data.ooyalaVideo;
  }
```

The Video object looks like this:

```
export interface Video {
  ooyalaId: String;
  pcode?: String;
  playerBrandingId?: String;
  skin?: Object;
  options?: Object;
}
```

I know the data is coming through ok, the problems looks like the 'options' Video object is always undefined, but I don't know why.

Comment: You never initialize this.options, so it's undefined. How is that surprising? Why do you think that should work?

Answer (score 2):

```
options
```

object is not defined in ngOnInit.

try

```
options: Video = new Video();
```

or something similar which would set up the options property.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you should be setting the property:

```
 @Input() data: Media;
 options: Video;

 constructor() { }

 ngOnInit() {
    this.options=new Video();
    console.log(this.data.ooyalaVideo);
    this.options.ooyalaId = this.data.ooyalaVideo;
  }
```